# Optimal setup for Stormcrawler -> Elasticsearch, if politeness of the crawl is not an issue?

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

Our university web system has roughly 1200 sites, comprising a couple million pages.  We have Stormcrawler installed and configured on a machine that has apache running locally, with a mapped drive to the file system for the web environment.  This means that we can have Stormcrawler crawl as fast as it wants with no network traffic being generated at all, and no effect on the public web presence.  We have the Tika parser running to index .doc, .pdf, etc.

- All websites are under the *.example.com domain.
- We have a single Elasticsearch instance running with plenty of CPU,
  Memory and Disk.
- The index-index has 4 shards.
- The metrics index has 1 shard.
- The status index has 10 shards.

With all of that in mind, what is the optimal crawling configuration we can do to get the crawler to ignore politeness and blast it's way through the local web environment and crawl everything as fast as possible?

Here are the current settings in the es-crawler.flux regarding spouts and bolts:

```
name: "www-all-crawler"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

    - resource: false
      file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
      override: true

    - resource: false
      file: "es-conf.yaml"
      override: true

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout"
    parallelism: 10

bolts:
  - id: "partitioner"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "fetcher"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
    parallelism: 2
  - id: "sitemap"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parse"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "index"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status_metrics"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "redirection_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.RedirectionBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "spout"
    to: "status_metrics"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE
  - from: "partitioner"
    to: "fetcher"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["key"]

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "sitemap"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "parse"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "parse"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"
  - from: "parse"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "index"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "parse"
    to: "redirection_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "parser_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "parser_bolt"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "parser_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
      streamId: "tika"
```

and the crawler-conf.yaml:

```
# Custom configuration for StormCrawler
# This is used to override the default values from crawler-default.xml and provide additional ones
# for your custom components.
# Use this file with the parameter -conf when launching your extension of ConfigurableTopology.
# This file does not contain all the key values but only the most frequently used ones. See crawler-default.xml for an extensive list.

config:
  topology.workers: 2
  topology.message.timeout.secs: 300
  topology.max.spout.pending: 100
  topology.debug: false

  fetcher.threads.number: 50

  # give 2gb to the workers
  worker.heap.memory.mb: 2048

  # mandatory when using Flux
  topology.kryo.register:
    - com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Metadata

  # metadata to transfer to the outlinks
  # used by Fetcher for redirections, sitemapparser, etc...
  # these are also persisted for the parent document (see below)
  # metadata.transfer:
  # - customMetadataName

  # lists the metadata to persist to storage
  # these are not transfered to the outlinks
  metadata.persist:
   - _redirTo
   - error.cause
   - error.source
   - isSitemap
   - isFeed

  http.agent.name: "Storm Crawler"
  http.agent.version: "1.0"
  http.agent.description: "built with StormCrawler Archetype 1.13"
  http.agent.url: "http://example.com/"
  http.agent.email: "noreply@example"

  # The maximum number of bytes for returned HTTP response bodies.
  # The fetched page will be trimmed to 65KB in this case
  # Set -1 to disable the limit.
  http.content.limit: 2000000
  jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: false


  # FetcherBolt queue dump => comment out to activate
  # if a file exists on the worker machine with the corresponding port number
  # the FetcherBolt will log the content of its internal queues to the logs
  # fetcherbolt.queue.debug.filepath: "/tmp/fetcher-dump-{port}"

  parsefilters.config.file: "parsefilters.json"
  urlfilters.config.file: "urlfilters.json"

  # revisit a page daily (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.default: 2880

  # revisit a page with a fetch error after 2 hours (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.fetch.error: 120

  # never revisit a page with an error (or set a value in minutes)
  ### Currently set to check back in 1 month.
  fetchInterval.error: 40320

  # text extraction for JSoupParserBolt
  textextractor.include.pattern:
   - DIV[id="block-edu-bootstrap-subtheme-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block"]
   - MAIN[role="main"]
   - DIV[id="content--news"]
   - DIV[id="content--person"]
   - ARTICLE[class="node container node--type-facility facility-full node-101895 node--promoted node--view-mode-full py-5"]
   - ARTICLE[class="node container node--type-spotlight spotlight-full node-90543 node--promoted node--view-mode-full py-5"]
   - DIV[class="field field--name-field-content field--type-entity-reference-revisions field--label-hidden field__items"]
   - ARTICLE
   - BODY
#   - DIV[id="maincontent"]
#   - DIV[itemprop="articleBody"]
#   - ARTICLE

  textextractor.exclude.tags:
   - STYLE
   - SCRIPT
   - FOOTER

  # custom fetch interval to be used when a document has the key/value in its metadata
  # and has been fetched successfully (value in minutes)
  # fetchInterval.FETCH_ERROR.isFeed=true: 30
  # fetchInterval.isFeed=true: 10

  # configuration for the classes extending AbstractIndexerBolt
  # indexer.md.filter: "someKey=aValue"
  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
  - domain=domain

  # Metrics consumers:
  topology.metrics.consumer.register:
     - class: "org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
       parallelism.hint: 1
```

and the es-conf.yaml:

```
# configuration for Elasticsearch resources

config:
  # ES indexer bolt
  # adresses can be specified as a full URL
  # if not we assume that the protocol is http and the port 9200
  es.indexer.addresses: "https://example.com:9200"
  es.indexer.index.name: "www-all-index"
  # es.indexer.pipeline: "_PIPELINE_"
  #### Check the document type thoroughly it needs to match with the elastic search index mapping ####
  es.indexer.doc.type: "doc"
  es.indexer.user: "{username}"
  es.indexer.password: "{password}"
  es.indexer.create: false
  #### Change the Cluster Name ####
  es.indexer.settings:
    cluster.name: "edu-web"

  # ES metricsConsumer
  es.metrics.addresses: "https://example.com:9200"
  es.metrics.index.name: "www-all-metrics"
  #### Check the document type thoroughly it needs to match with the elastic search index mapping ####
  es.metrics.doc.type: "datapoint"
  es.metrics.user: "{username}"
  es.metrics.password: "{password}"
  #### Change the Cluster Name ####
  es.metrics.settings:
    cluster.name: "edu-web"

  # ES spout and persistence bolt
  es.status.addresses: "https://example.com:9200"
  es.status.index.name: "www-all-status"
  #### Check the document type thoroughly it needs to match with the elastic search index mapping ####
  es.status.doc.type: "status"
  es.status.user: "{username}"
  es.status.password: "{password}"
  # the routing is done on the value of 'partition.url.mode'
  es.status.routing: true
  # stores the value used for the routing as a separate field
  # needed by the spout implementations
  es.status.routing.fieldname: "metadata.hostname"
  es.status.bulkActions: 500
  es.status.flushInterval: "5s"
  es.status.concurrentRequests: 1
  #### Change the Cluster Name ####
  es.status.settings:
    cluster.name: "edu-web"

  ################
  # spout config #
  ################

  # positive or negative filter parsable by the Lucene Query Parser
  # es.status.filterQuery: "-(metadata.hostname:stormcrawler.net)"

  # time in secs for which the URLs will be considered for fetching after a ack of fail
  spout.ttl.purgatory: 30

  # Min time (in msecs) to allow between 2 successive queries to ES
  spout.min.delay.queries: 1000

  # Delay since previous query date (in secs) after which the nextFetchDate value will be reset to the current time
  # Setting this to -1 or a large value means that the ES will cache the results but also that less and less results
  # might be returned.
  spout.reset.fetchdate.after: 120

  es.status.max.buckets: 50
  es.status.max.urls.per.bucket: 20
  # field to group the URLs into buckets
  es.status.bucket.field: "metadata.hostname"
  # field to sort the URLs within a bucket
  es.status.bucket.sort.field: "nextFetchDate"
  # field to sort the buckets
  es.status.global.sort.field: "nextFetchDate"

  # CollapsingSpout : limits the deep paging by resetting the start offset for the ES query
  es.status.max.start.offset: 500

  # AggregationSpout : sampling improves the performance on large crawls
  es.status.sample: false

  # AggregationSpout (expert): adds this value in mins to the latest date returned in the results and
  # use it as nextFetchDate
  es.status.recentDate.increase: -1
  es.status.recentDate.min.gap: -1
  topology.metrics.consumer.register:
       - class: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.MetricsConsumer"
         parallelism.hint: 1
         #whitelist:
         #  - "fetcher_counter"
         #  - "fetcher_average.bytes_fetched"
         #blacklist:
         #  - "__receive.*"
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>www.all.edu</groupId>
        <artifactId>www-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <stormcrawler.version>1.13</stormcrawler.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.2</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.8</source>
                                        <target>1.8</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.3.2</version>
                                <executions>
                                        <execution>
                                                <goals>
                                                        <goal>exec</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                        </execution>
                                </executions>
                                <configuration>
                                        <executable>java</executable>
                                        <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                                        <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                                        <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.3.3</version>
                                <executions>
                                        <execution>
                                                <phase>package</phase>
                                                <goals>
                                                        <goal>shade</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                                <configuration>
                                                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                                                        <transformers>
                                                                <transformer
                                                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                                                <transformer
                                                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                                                        <mainClass>org.apache.storm.flux.Flux</mainClass>
                                                                        <manifestEntries>
                                                                                <Change></Change>
                                                                                <Build-Date></Build-Date>
                                                                        </manifestEntries>
                                                                </transformer>
                                                        </transformers>
                                                        <!-- The filters below are necessary if you want to include the Tika
                                                                module -->
                                                        <filters>
                                                                <filter>
                                                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                                                        <excludes>
                                                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                                                        </excludes>
                                                                </filter>
                                                                <filter>
                                                                        <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2428 -->
                                                                        <artifact>org.apache.storm:flux-core</artifact>
                                                                        <excludes>
                                                                                <exclude>org/apache/commons/**</exclude>
                                                                                <exclude>org/apache/http/**</exclude>
                                                                                <exclude>org/yaml/**</exclude>
                                                                        </excludes>
                                                                </filter>
                                                        </filters>
                                                </configuration>
                                        </execution>
                                </executions>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>storm-crawler-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${stormcrawler.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>storm-crawler-tika</artifactId>
                        <version>${stormcrawler.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                        <version>${stormcrawler.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.2</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flux-core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you please post your conf? do your sites have robots.txt files?

Comment: Some have robots.txt, some do not.  When I say we have 1200 different sites, what we have is 1200 different sites that all are for the most part sub-directories of the www.example.com domain, with just a few that are host1.example.com, and host2.example.com.  For the most part they are all subdirectories.  the conf files are, for the most part, set at defaults, but I will post them below.

Comment: EDIT: I added the configs to the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so you are in fact dealing with a low number of distinct hostnames. You could have it all on a single ES shard with a single ES spout really. The main point is that the fetcher will be enforcing politeness based on the hostname and the crawl will be relatively slow. You probably don't need more than one instance of the FetcherBolt either.

Since you are crawling your own sites, you could be more aggressive with the crawler and allow multiple fetch threads to pull from the same hostname concurrently, try setting

*fetcher.threads.per.queue: 25*

and also retrieve more URLs from each query to ES with

*es.status.max.urls.per.bucket: 200*

that should make your crawl a lot faster.

BTW: could you please drop me an email if you're OK being listed in https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Powered-By
?

NOTE to other readers: this is advisable only if you are crawling your own sites. Being aggressive to third-party sites is impolite and improductive as you risk to be blacklisted.